# Firebase Recycler Adapter giving an error

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebaseui

Am trying to populate a recyclerView with some cartItems(model class) but the app keeps crashing. The error message I got from the logs:

```
2022-03-03 10:00:11.060 3810-4183/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to get FIS auth token
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: adly: Firebase Installations Service is unavailable. Please try again later.
    at ljb.X(PG:5)
    at ljb.C(PG:7)
    at aecs.g(PG:14)
    at adlk.a(PG:14)
    at mdx.run(PG:19)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at lsi.run(PG:2)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: adly: Firebase Installations Service is unavailable. Please try again later.
    at admj.b(PG:54)
    at adlv.run(PG:15)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

2022-03-03 10:00:12.662 3810-4182/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions: FIS_AUTH_ERROR. Won't retry the operation.

My Fireebase recycler options and adapter code:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("Cart List")
                .child("User View")
                .child(Prevalent.currentOnlineUsr.getPhone())
                .child("Products")
                .limitToLast(10);

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<CartItem> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<CartItem>()
                        .setQuery(query, CartItem.class).build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CartItem, CartViewHolder> adapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CartItem, CartViewHolder>(options) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull CartItem model) {
                        holder.txtProductName.setText(model.getPname());
                        holder.txtProductPrice.setText(model.getPrice());
                        holder.txtProductQuantity.setText(model.getQuantity());

                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public CartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                                .inflate(R.layout.cart_item_layout, parent,false);
                        return new CartViewHolder(view);
                    }
                };
        cart_Recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
```

I don't know if there is need for the ViewHolder class or the model class. What's really puzzling me is am using the same method on the home activity to populate the home recycler and it works without any errors.

Answer (score 2):

You got an error Firebase Installation Service not working.
It turns out that new versions of Firebase SDKs depend on a new internal infrastructure service, called FIS (the Firebase Installations Service) for targeting identifiers ("FIDs" or "Instance-IDs").
If you are using API key restrictions for the API keys you use in your application, you will have to extend those restrictions to allow usage with the new Firebase Installations Service at firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com.

To allow your API key in question to be used with the new Firebase Installations API:

1. go to the Google Cloud Console
2. choose the relevant project (i.e. the project you use for your application)
3. open the menu and go to APIs & Services -> Credentials
4. click Edit API key for the API key in question
5. scroll down to API restrictions
6. from the dropdown, choose Firebase Installations API
   click Save
7. wait a couple of minutes for Google servers to update and retry...

Comment: I followed your instructions took me a while and a fresh mind, google cloud is huge and I have never seen it before. I didn't know firebase was part of google cloud. Anyway I completely didn't have any API key so I made one. How do I pass it to my app to make sure its the one its using?

Comment: @Frank or better yet direct me to a documentation or tutorial that explains the relationship between the two and how firebase is affected. I will be extremely grateful.

Comment: Thank you for this question and thank you for your input here Frank.  Both came in useful today.  To answer your secondary question Bryne, it seems that the API key won't need a secondary call within your app's code, as it functions in association with your Flutter project, in the background, as a requisite for the Firebase functions you call from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Could try creating a new project in Android Studio, and try everything from zero, in particular your project files that are needed for you to figure out what's the problem.
Create a new database in Firebase, try switching regions this time (I don't recommend Europe because of bucket errors that I had in multiple occasions...)

Comment: Okay Let me try that... And I actually selected Europe for my location..  @Oneke Thanks for coming back to advise I really appreciate it

Comment: @BrynePhiri tried it out? I am sure it's because it is Europe region